# dot product of dense vectors with nulls

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using spark with scala and trying to do the following.

I have two dense vectors(created using Vectors.dense), and I need to find the dot product of these. How could I accomplish this?

Also, I am creating the vectors based on an input file which is comma seperated. However some values are missing. Is there an easy way to read these values as zero instead of null when I am creating the vectors?

For example:

input file: 3,1,,,2

created vector: 3,1,0,0,2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2):

Spark vectors are just wrappers for arrays, internally they get converted to Breeze arrays for vector/matrix operations. You can do just that manually to get the dot product:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors, DenseVector}
import breeze.linalg.{DenseVector => BDV, SparseVector => BSV, Vector => BV}

val dv1: Vector = Vectors.dense(1.0, 0.0, 3.0)
val bdv1 = new BDV(dv1.toArray)

val dv2: Vector = Vectors.dense(2.0, 0.0, 0.0)
val bdv2 = new BDV(dv2.toArray)

scala> bdv1 dot bdv2
res3: Double = 2.0
```

For your second question, you can do something like this:

```
val v: String = "3,1,,,2"

scala> v.split("\\,").map(r => if (r == "") 0 else r.toInt)
res4: Array[Int] = Array(3, 1, 0, 0, 2)
```